# Rails: Except array elements from slice

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have record of **students** like

`{"id"=>"14", "first_name"=>"Donald",  "last_name"=>"Trophy", "age"=>"13", "gender"=>"male", "cast"=>"black", "fee_status"=>"paid", "deleted_at"=>nil}`

To send data to DataTable I am taking some columns

```
patient.slice('age', 'gender', 'cast', 'fee_status').values
```

I have another array coming from some flow, `hidden_columns` which can have following value:

`["age"]`

`["age", "gender"]`

`["31", "33", "age"]`

`["31", "gender", "33", "age"]`

I want to `except` the values I have in `hidden_columns`

What I am trying is:

```
patient.slice('age', 'gender', 'cast', 'fee_status').except(hidden_columns).values
```

which is not working for me.

Comment: Why not go ahead and do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you have to use `splat` (*) operator. Then instead of using `.slice()` and `.except()` together, you can do this is more efficient way.

```
columns_to_show = ['age', 'gender', 'cast', 'fee_status']
columns_to_show = columns_to_show - hidden_columns if hidden_columns

patient.slice(*columns_to_show).values
```

Answer (score 5):

You'll have to use the splat operator inside `except` as it accepts multiple keys as arguments, not an array of keys,

```
patient.slice('age', 'gender', 'cast', 'fee_status').except(*hidden_columns)
 => {"cast"=>"black", "fee_status"=>"paid"}
```